# Carregar aba somente ao clicar(com jquery)

Tags: jquery, load, aba

Estou usando o sistema de abas com [jqueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) e me deparei com um problema onde eu preciso que ao carregar a página, somente carregue a primeira aba, existe um modo de fazer isso?

Comment: Mas para que serveria então as outras abas?

Comment: Isso é facil, agora me diga, quando é que as outras abas poderão ser visíveis?

Comment: uma forma seria vc dizer no jquery q as outras abas iniciam ocultas e qnd um input da aba exibida for preenchido, a seguinte seria exibida. não entendi como seria o clique se as outras estariam ocultas.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o AJAX para fazer o carregamento das abas, assim que o usuário clicar na aba, uma função, por exemplo, carregar() é disparada para cada aba e carrega o conteúdo.

Comment: LeAndrade, as outras abas servem para o conteúdo dela, eu só quero fazer isso por que há conteúdos na aba, como o do google maps que carrega ao carregar a página, na primeira aba não tem nada que precise carregar assim, portanto uma pessoa que entra na página teria que esperar carregar todo conteúdo da página que não está vendo, isso meio que é um incoveniente, por isso que fazer

Answer (score 0):

Cara basicamente é isto que está no exemplo. Na **ABA 1** você carrega o conteúdo na página mesmo, nas outras abas, você carrega um html diferente para cada uma.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
      beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {      // função se houver algum erro
          ui.panel.html(
            "Mensagens de erro caso o conteúdo não seja carregado por algum motivo" );
        });
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="arquivoTab2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="arquivoTab3.html">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="arquivoTab4.html">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>TEXTO QUE JÁ VEM PRE CARREGADO QUANDO VOCÊ ACESSAR A PÁGINA.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: não acho que vc não entendeu, eu não quero criar página html e sim deixar tudo na mesma página, mas só carregar o conteúdo da primeira aba+o restante em torno da página

Comment: Sem deixar html separados, com Ajax, não vai funcionar. Terá que buscar uma outra tecnologia que carregue elementos da própria página por eventos.

Comment: blz obrigado pela resposta